Why is it hard to write a linux OS for apples ARM chips?
To my understanding: different architecture -> different cpu instructions -> different sequences of 0/1 -> need for a compiler (since most of the OS is written in C or another high level language) that translates to this different sequence of 0/1. And this should be sufficient if we assume a boot loader can be written with manageable effort and every C code instruction can be translated into a sequence of apple silicon cpu instructions so that they carry out the same thing as for example on x86-64.
I know only of the ashahi linux project so why is my reasoning flawed? Thanks! it would help me to connect the dots a bit more.

Interesting question but I’m not sure it has anything to do with Ubuntu?!

Well writing any Linux OS is hard imo. If not everyone would do it. Maybe you should try to. I imagine that since everything is open source that you could make your own little spin of it. Personally I don't own one of these machines but I'd love to see some crazy lightweight spin. Like make it use 128mb at idle, that way even the lowest end models of m1 chips can still run it for a long time. 128mb is kinda a hyperbole. I feel like if it's less than a 1gb at idle with how things are right now on x64 you're probably alright. You need to run a desktop that's lightweight and versatile. I'd say Mate because I'm a bit of an old head but Ubuntu has themes for it that make it look like Windows, Mac, or even like Ubuntu's vanilla theme without sacrificing RAM. I usually sit at about 800mb at idle using Mate. I'm not using it right now though lol, gnome got me a little hooked these days

Ubuntu 24.10 Concept Snapdragon X Elite is another project that aims to port Ubuntu to Qualcomm (ARM-based) Snapdragon laptops. It is not compatible with Apple silicon M series processors, however I thought it would be relevant to post about it on Ask Ubuntu because this image is based on the latest Ubuntu 24.10 (oracular oriole) release.

Note the Linux 6.11.0-23-qcom-x1e kernel version.
